# I want to change name format based on selected language

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 languages in my application english and hebrew,

- when i select english the name format should be first name and last name,
- if i choose hebrew format should be last name and first name.

when i click on english it works fine but when i choose hebrew it does not working.

in my html

```
  <div> {{fullname}}</div>
```

in my script

```
 if(vm.userIdentity.language!="he"){
    $scope.fullname=vm.userIdentity.firstname+" "+vm.userIdentity.lastname;
 } else{
    $scope.fullname=vm.userIdentity.lastname+" "+vm.userIdentity.firstname;
 }
```

Comment: What is the value of `vm.userIdentity.language` when it doesn't work?

Comment: Make sure vm.userIdentity isn't being set async, otherwise you'll have to wrap it in a callback or something.

Comment: vm.userIdentity.language takes correct value.i checked that.It works fine for english language but its not working for hebrew

Comment: I need help very urjent

Comment: @rajasekhar Can you post more code? I dont know what `vm` refers to in your code. And where this piece of code is running?

Comment: do console.log(vm.userIdentity.language) before your if condition and see what is the value